# How to debug LoadLibraryEx when used from C#

Tags: c#, pinvoke, loadlibrary

I am trying to load a win32 dll in  C# using the LoadLibraryEx.

It is not working -  I get a message stating in visual studio "vshost32.exe has stopped working". No exceptions or any clue as to why it doesn't work.

I don't believe it is a dependency problem because if I alter the search paths for the dependencies I get a message box stating "xyz.dll could not be found".

I am wondering if there is a way I can find out why it doesn't load properly. The program stops working on the line:

```
IntPtr pDll = LoadLibraryEx(@"C:\Program Files\XXX\XXX.dll", IntPtr.Zero, flags);
```

---

```
[UnmanagedFunctionPointer(CallingConvention.StdCall)]
    private delegate void ImportResults();

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr LoadLibraryEx(string dllToLoad, IntPtr hFile, LoadLibraryFlags flags);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

    [DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
    public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    [System.Flags]
    public enum LoadLibraryFlags : uint
    {
        DONT_RESOLVE_DLL_REFERENCES = 0x00000001,
        LOAD_IGNORE_CODE_AUTHZ_LEVEL = 0x00000010,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE = 0x00000002,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_DATAFILE_EXCLUSIVE = 0x00000040,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_AS_IMAGE_RESOURCE = 0x00000020,
        LOAD_WITH_ALTERED_SEARCH_PATH = 0x00000008,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR = 0x00000100,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_SYSTEM32 = 0x00000800,
        LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS = 0x00001000
    }

    public void Import()
    {
        LoadLibraryFlags flags = LoadLibraryFlags.LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DEFAULT_DIRS |
                                 LoadLibraryFlags.LOAD_LIBRARY_SEARCH_DLL_LOAD_DIR;

        IntPtr pDll = LoadLibraryEx(@"C:\Program Files\XXX\XXX.dll", IntPtr.Zero, flags);

        IntPtr pAddressOfFunctionToCall = GetProcAddress(pDll, "ImportResults");


        ImportResults import = (ImportResults)Marshal.GetDelegateForFunctionPointer(pAddressOfFunctionToCall,
                                                                               typeof(ImportResults));
        import();

        bool result = FreeLibrary(pDll);

    }
```

Update:

I have downloaded the windows sdk and am attempting to use the cdb.exe to debug the problem using the process described here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2006/11/20/debugging-loadlibrary-failures.aspx

When running the utility I am using this command line:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\cdb.exe" loadlib "C:\Program Files\XXX\XXX\XXX.DLL"
```

But I get this error:
[image: Error]

The file definitely exists so I am unsure what I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Enable debugging of unmanaged code in VS and debug from VS

Comment: Possibly, your dll is found, but it requires one or more different dll's that are missing somehow. Does your dll requires other dll (I.e. is statically linked to other dll that maybe are not in the same path?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I installed the windows debugging tools: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/desktop/bg162891

I then downloaded the Windows Symbol packages: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg463028.aspx

Then set an environment variable to tell the debugger where to look for symbols:

```
_NT_SYMBOL_PATH = SRV*C:\dev\symbols*http://msdl.microsoft.com/download/symbols;C:\Symbols
```

(I installed the symbol package to C:\Symbols)

Then I started my application and attached the debugger with this command:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\Debuggers\x86\cdb.exe" -pb -p <pid>
```

-pb means it won't break on exceptions
-p is the pid of the thread you want to debug

From this I have been able to determine where the error is happening. Still haven't figured out why it's happening though.